# Shortest code for getting all K-item combinations of N-item array, where K <= N

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, combinations, instance-eval

What is the shortest way of getting all K-item combinations of an N-item array where K <= N?  I managed to write down the one below :

```
 > [1,2,3].instance_eval "(1..size).flat_map {|i| self.combination(i).to_a }"

=> [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Any ideas how to get rid of "instance_eval"?  It doesn't seem to be very elagant :\

Comment: what about assigning `[1,2,3]` to a name? Like `ary = [1,2,3]` and then `(1..ary.size).flat_map {|i| ary.combination(i).to_a }`

Seems pretty straighforward

Comment: Why do you care about "shortest"? Code length isn't very important.

Comment: @NiklasB. nice, should be an answer

Comment: @muistooshort - I don't care that much - code was already shipped with 1.'upto'( ... method ... I just wanted to widen my horizons :).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cool, short way to implement a "power set" function, if order/empty list doesn't matter:

```
>>> [nil].product(*[1, 2, 3].map { |x| [nil, x] }).map(&:compact)
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: thanks ... IMHO you did the trick and forced me to learn something new

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
x = [1,2,3]
1.upto(x.size).flat_map { |i| x.combination(i).to_a }
#=> [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

(2**arr.size).times.map do |i|
  arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e,j),a| a << e if i[j] == 1 }
end
  #=> [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 4],
  # [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

You could, of course, sort the array that is returned however you like. For example:

```
(2**arr.size).times.map do |i|
  arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e,j),a| a << e if i[j] == 1 }
end.sort_by { |a| [a.size,a] }
  #=> [[],
  #    [1], [2], [3], [4],
  #    [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4],
  #    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: let me add a comment for how this works: it loops from `0` to `1111` in binary. If size of `arr` is 6, then it is from `0` to `111111`, etc. Then it just check if it is 0 or 1 for the bit, to decide whether to include that element. For example, for `1011` and `arr = [1,2,3,4]`, then add 1, 3, 4 and that makes it `[1, 3, 4]`

Comment: @太極者無極而生, thanks for the explanation. I normally provide one; don't know why I didn't provide one here.

Answer (score 0):

One version, hope it's correct.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
1.upto(x.size).reduce([]) { |a, i| a + x.permutation(i).map(&:sort).uniq.to_a }
# => [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Not the most efficient way of generating combinations: `[1,2,3,4].permutation(3).map(&:sort).uniq == [1,2,3,4].combination(3).to_a #=> true`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, you are rigtht. I prefer the solution in the comments by niklas-b but I read it afterwards. At this is also a short solution.